# Use factory object to initialize base class

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a baseclass whose objects I always want to create with a factory object.

```
class Shape:
  def __init__(self):
    pass

class ShapeMgr:
  def __init__(self):
    self.allShapes = []

  def new(self):
    newShape = Shape()
    self.allShapes.append( newShape )
    return newShape
```

I also have derived classes from that base class.

```
class Circle(Shape):
  def __init__(self):
    pass
```

I want to initialize the base class of the derived class objects from the factory object.  IE, I want to **create the Shape part of the Circle by calling ShapeMgr.new()**.

I've tried defining the Shape constructor as follows:

```
SM = ShapeMgr()
class Circle:
  def __init__(self):
    global SM
    super() = SM.new()
```

But it tells me that I cannot assign to the result of a function call.  If I instead try:

```
    self = SM.new()
```

Then later on when I try to access Circle methods, it says that Shapes don't have the Circle methods.

Is there any way to use a factory to create the base class portion of a derived class object?

Comment: Does each child of shape really need its own manager?

Comment: Each of your `def`s should have `self` as the first parameter.

Comment: -Ignacio: Yes, in my actual application.  But it's irrelevant to the question, so I've removed it.
-Ethan: fixed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want `Circle` to call `Shape` for initialization, just do so:

```
class Circle(Shape):
    def __init__(self):  # important!
        super().__init__()
```

If your goal is to have `Circle`s end up in `ShapeMgr`, you don't need to worry about the base class (`Shape`) at all, because nothing in `Shape` causes registration to happn.

Change `ShapeMgr.new()` to accept an optional object to register, and if no object is given then create a new `Shape`:

```
def new(self, obj=None):
    if obj is None:
        obj = Shape()
    self.allShapes.append(obj)
```

Please note that `self` must be declared in Python -- your methods will not work correctly without it.

Comment: Maybe it wasn't emphasized enough- I don't want to call Shape's constructor.  I want to call SM.new() so that it's registered with the ShapeMgr.